# How can I return char array with boost::optional

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-optional

I try to return simple array with boost::optional

```
boost::optional<const char *> foo () {
   char ar[100] = {};
   return boost::make_optional(true, ar);
}
```

and I got the following error:

> ```
> could not convert ‘boost::make_optional(bool, const T&) [with T = char [100]](ar)’ from ‘boost::optional<char [100]>’ to ‘boost::optional<const char*>’ return boost::make_optional(true, ar);
> ```

How can I handle such confusion?

Comment: Er, you *don't!* If you want to have a string then use `std::string`. If you want a run-time changeable vector then use `std::vector`. If you want an array with a size fixed at compile-time then use `std::array`.

Comment: As for your problem, arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. Read the error message again, and see what it deduces the type of `ar` to be. Then compare it to what you say the return type is.

Comment: But I know that name of array is a pointer to a first element of array. Strange...

Comment: No, an array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. But it *isn't* by itself a pointer. That is, you can decay `ar` to `&ar[0]`, but you can't use it when returning since that will return a pointer to a variable that cease to exist and will disappear directly once the function returns.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::make_optional` deduced `ar` as `char [100]` type, but it expected `const char *`. By default implicit casting is not happened in template parameter deduction.

If you want to use raw pointer, it is possible to use the following solution:

```
boost::optional<const char *> foo () {
    char ar[100] = {};
    return boost::make_optional(true, static_cast<const char *>(ar));
}
```

But in this case you lose information how many elements located in this array and maybe better to use in `foo()` function `std::vector` or `std::array` as in example of **sehe**

Good luck !!

Answer (score 3):

Closest you can do is by using a wrapper with value semantics.

That wrapper is `std::array`:

```
boost::optional<std::array<char, 100> > foo () {
   std::array<char, 100> ar {};
   return boost::make_optional(true, ar);
}
```

About arrays vs. pointers:

- [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)